# Switch case needs a little update

Tags: switch-statement

I'm building a debounce timer using switch cases.

I enter "case 1" but it never continues after `if (in_1_timerTimeout)`, and I have no idea why. Can someone figure out what is missing?

So far I've checked, that the code exists "case 0" and entering "case 1", but it stop there. I have a feeling I might be interpreting `if (in_1_timerTimeout)` wrong, so I doesn't use it properly.

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "stdbool.h"

unsigned long in_1_timer = 0;
unsigned long in_1_state = 0;

bool in_1_timerTimeout = false;
bool in_1 = false;


void myInterruptHandler(void)
{

}

void handleInputFilter(void)
{
    switch (in_1_state)
    {
        case 0:
            if (!in_button_GetValue())
            {
                in_1_timer        = 1000;
                in_1_timerTimeout = false;
                in_1_state        = 1;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (!in_button_GetValue())
            { 
                //programmet kører hertil, men kommer ikke videre til næste "if"
                if (in_1_timerTimeout)
                { 
                    in_1_state       = 2;
                    in_1             = true;
                    //out_LED_SetHigh();
                }
            } else in_1_state     = 0;
            break;

        case 2:

            if (in_button_GetValue())
            {
                in_1_timer        = 1000;
                in_1_timerTimeout = false;
                in_1_state        = 3;
            }
            break; 

        case 3:

            if (in_button_GetValue())
            {
                if (in_1_timerTimeout)
                {
                    in_1_state        = 0;
                    in_1              = false;
                    //out_LED_SetLow();
                }
            } else in_1_state     = 2;
            break;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    while (1)
    {
        handleInputFilter();
        // Add your application code
    }
}
```

Comment: In the given context, I don't see any place where `in_1_timerTimeout` is set to true, due to that, it'll always skip `if (in_1_timerTimeout)`, because it stays false.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out, i hadn't made the entirety of the timer, so as you said, i never made the in_1_timerTimeout go true to interrupt. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped out, I'll make an answer from my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given context, I don't see any place where `in_1_timerTimeout` is set to true.

Due to this, it'll always skip `if (in_1_timerTimeout)`, because it stays false.

I don't see any issues with your switch statement, that's working fine as is.